# What do you think about a "Notify me again later" feature?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, notifications

At times, I am able to frequently check SO for answers. However, sometimes, I discover a very interesting answer or comment that needs more time for thinking and replying.

Unfortunately, I'm not always free, sometimes I have to delay those writings until I'm at home. Later on, it's very hard to remember or find it again, even if it was very interesting because I forget everything while working.(you know, context switching) Finally, at home, there are many other new notifications, and I'll forget completely about notifications in which I was previously interested (and usually needs more care).

So, I wanted a feature like **Notify Me Again Later** button. This would look like *mark as unread* of email client. This would be a way of making a *job queue*. If the manually queued notification is displayed with different color (for example *blue*?) it would be nice.

Anyway, the gained benefit would be a lot more than increased complexity of the UI.

What do you think about this?

Comment: I use Favorites for this (the star you see under the question), although my "unanswered" favorites list has now grown so large I'll never get back to them all.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Because I'm using Favorite for real Favorite purpose, I can't use it for list of temporarily delayed notifications.

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this already.  If you perform *any* activity on a post, it shows up in your activity list, and you get notifications for comment replies (like this one).

Answer (score -12):

I suggest SO creating a temporary favorite that will auto delete each entry after a configurable period, for example auto delete a particular favorite entry after 2 days or a week. That will prevent the abuse of favorite functionality and serve as **perishable** reminder

p/s: I can't post this as a feature request because I'm no longer able to post question on meta.

Comment: There's reason for it. 2 posts and both with -16 downvotes & +0 upvotes

Comment: @genesis-φ: It takes 2 posts to ban a user? Not fair enough, in my opinion.

Comment: yes, it doesn't for me either. On META, there shouldn't be this punishing turned on

Comment: @genesis-φ: Can you help me to remove the ban?

Comment: I can't. Post few good answers and you might get second chance